# Why gitignore playground.xcworkspace for Xcode Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: xcode, gitignore, swift-playground

A couple of published `.gitignore` files include `playground.xcworkspace`. Does anyone know a good reason why?

References
https://www.gitignore.io/api/xcode,swift
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore#L35

Comment: It does seem like a possible mistake; you'd think what they'd want to exclude is just the xcuserdata. However, I can't see that excluding it would do any harm either.

Comment: Right, `xcuserdata/` should suffice